# Unable to get key from ConfigParser value

Tags: python

1. I create .txt file inside the same folder to store Api Key, user name, etc... as you can see in Image 1
2. in Image 2 you will find how I enter the info (Using = and no '')
3. With this code I´m trying to import data from the .txt file into the code (Image 3):

   ```
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read("config.ini")
    api_id = config['Telegram']['api_id']
    api_hash = config['Telegram']['api_hash']
    api_hash = str(api_hash)
    phone = config['Telegram']['phone']
    username = config['Telegram']['username']
   ```

And I´m getting the next error as you can see in Image 3.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-26acbcbbad1b> in <module>
      4 
      5 # Setting configuration values
----> 6 api_id = config['Telegram']['api_id']
      7 api_hash = config['Telegram']['api_hash']
      8 

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/configparser.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    956     def __getitem__(self, key):
    957         if key != self.default_section and not self.has_section(key):
--> 958             raise KeyError(key)
    959         return self._proxies[key]
    960 

KeyError: 'Telegram'
```

What I´m doing wrong?

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

[image: Image 3]

Comment: `config` doesn't have `"Telegram"` key. Double check your data.

Comment: "Telegram" is the first line in the .txt file as you can see image #2,. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 1):

You are giving wrong path in `config.read()`.

Try absolute path, It should work

```
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read("/path/to/config.ini")
```

Use the actual path, which you can get from right click on this file.